# Fill a PHP/HTML field in a website

Tags: java, php, html, forms, fill

I want to automatically fill the field called "email" of a webpage thesite.com/email.php, which code is something similar to this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="24">
<br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

And then, after filling the field, I also would like to perform the action "submit".
But I don't know actually how to do that with Java
Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you trying to submit the form automatically with a java application?

Comment: Huh?! Java? PHP? You can only have one flavour; vanilla and not both.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to submit automatically this form via a java application

Comment: So, show your relevant code.

Comment: Now, did you mean "java" or "javascript"? Those are two different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: Well, usually with .html websites I used to fill forms opening links like "http://mthesite.com/thepage.html?email=mymail@myprovider.com&message=Hi!" in my java application with the method .setPage() (JEditorPane) and that worked for me

Comment: You have answers below. One in pure PHP, another using JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically submit the form with java, you don't directly fill the form, rather send the form information to the submit page via HTTP GET or POST. You did not provide the  onsubmit value in your post, but you would use that webpage URL and send the form information via a URLConnection. If using GET, you send the data in a query string (where key/value are the form parameters):

```
URL url = new URL("http://mywebsite/form-submit-webpage.php?key1=value1&key2=value2");
```

If POST, you must use the OutputStream of URL connection to set the POST key/value pairs

```
URL url = new URL("http://mywebsite/form-submit-webpage.php");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
//write key value pairs to os.
```

From their, get get the InputStream from the URLConnection to read the results. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a form in html and a form handler in php.

HTML code posting the information to "welcome.php"

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php can handle the variables in different ways.  Here is an example:

```
<html>
<body>

    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The file will pass the variables by their names.  In this example, the names are "name" and "email" using the post method.  In the php file, you receive the variables useing the $_POST method.

Comment: Using a POST method with GET arrays; that won't work.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.  Thanks Fred -ii-