# Playing with html forms using java

Tags: java, html, forms, url, web

i wish to learn how to send data&information from java program to an html file

i.e i have html form :

```
 <html>
<body>

<form action="for.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the idea is , is it possible to do like this :

```
String name = "Maher";
String email = "maher@hotmail.com";
```

then send this information to the forms and submit it

any idea  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill a PHP/HTML field in a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286289/fill-a-php-html-field-in-a-website)

Comment: Are you using JSP, because I have a solution for it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using normal java, then you could do this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://mywebsite/for.php?name=Maher&email=maher@hotmail.com");
```

If you are using jsp, then do this:

*Java*

```
String name = "Maher";
String email = "maher@hotmail.com";
request.sendAttribute("name",name);
request.sendAttribute("email",email);
```

*Html*

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="for.php" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="${name}"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="${email}"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```